# Independent watchdog timer is not accurate as expected

Tags: stm32

Here is my source code:

```
  void CLOCK(void){
    
    RCC_DeInit();   
    
    RCC_LSICmd(ENABLE);
    
    RCC_HSEConfig(RCC_HSE_ON);
    while(RCC_WaitForHSEStartUp()==ERROR);
    
    FLASH_PrefetchBufferCmd(FLASH_PrefetchBuffer_Enable);   
    FLASH_SetLatency(FLASH_Latency_2);  
    
    RCC_PLL2Cmd(DISABLE);

    RCC_PLLCmd(DISABLE);
    RCC_PREDIV1Config(RCC_PREDIV1_Source_HSE,RCC_PREDIV1_Div1); 
    RCC_PLLConfig(RCC_PLLSource_PREDIV1,RCC_PLLMul_8);
    RCC_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
    
    while(RCC_GetFlagStatus(RCC_FLAG_PLLRDY)!=SET);
    
    RCC_SYSCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLKSource_PLLCLK);

    RCC_HCLKConfig(RCC_SYSCLK_Div1);
    RCC_PCLK1Config(RCC_HCLK_Div2);
    RCC_PCLK2Config(RCC_HCLK_Div1);
    
    while (RCC_GetSYSCLKSource() != 0x08){} 
        

}

int main(){ 
    unsigned long int counter;  
    CLOCK();
    GPIOS();

        IWDG_WriteAccessCmd(IWDG_WriteAccess_Enable);
        IWDG_SetPrescaler(IWDG_Prescaler_32);
        IWDG_SetReload(500);
        IWDG_Enable();

    while(1)
        {   
            counter=counter+1;      
            Print(counter);
            if(counter>6553500){counter=0;}
            IWDG_ReloadCounter();           
        }
    
}
```

I have set my watchdog counter to 309( 1 second)(Stm32f107, LSI=40Khz,Prescale=32 ). By ignoring the "IWDG_ReloadCounter(); " (I commented //IWDG_ReloadCounter();) , this watchdog resets my MCU after about 3 seconds instead of 1 seconds. I need what my problem is.

Comment: Which exact STM10x model this is? Is the WDT code generated by CubeMX or did you add it yourself? Do you have a interrupt handler defined for the watchdog interrupt?

Comment: Thank you very much Justme for your comment. I just updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it's a old thread, there is nothing wrong with IWDG but with your correct sequence of setting new values.

IWDG is clocked by 40 KHz LSI clock, or, will tick at 25 uS
When you set a prescaler, will slow down the count rate with

```
25 uS * 32 = 0.8 mS per tick
```

If you don't set a reload value, the natural overflow will be at

```
2^12 (for 12 bits counter) = 4096 ticks * 0.8 mS = 3.2768 Sec
```

If you set a reload value, basically you will force the counter to count only from this value (down to 0), at the same tick rate

```
500 * 0.8 mS = 0.4 Sec
```

Furthermore, if you enable windowed option by writing another value to WINR, this value will limit your feed point in time. In example above, counter will count down from 500 -> 0. If you set

```
WINR = 100
```

You are allowed to feed in a tinny window, when counter is < 100 but > 0
Any write when counter is > 100 up to 500 will determine a reset due to incorrect point in time feed.

But you see those 3.2 Sec because you didn't follow correct sequence of initialization, so your IWDG will not use your reload value.

I suspect you need to wait correct SR flags to be 0 before any write.

Windowed explained

[image]

**Personal note**

When use 2 separate clocks and windowed mode

- one is LSI to run the IWDG
- one AHB to run the CPU to feed the IWDG from SW application

In reality, they will shift in respect to each other, due to thermal drift.
This will translate that your window will shift in respect to feed point.

Even if you set the feed point (from practical measurements) at mid window, you you run the MCU long enough, the window will still shift :)))

This is hard to calculate & predict over the full temp range.
And of course, any SW modification will impact the feed point, unless you use a TIM + IRQ to do that but in this case, the IRQ priority must be lower than any executing code in entire system.

Special care will need to be taken in this case to avoid wrong feed.